# Filtering out email addresses from ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: iphone, filtering, addressbook

I'm using ABPeoplePicker to show a list of contacts.

I'd like to filter this list of contacts to *only* show the contacts that have email addresses.  How would I do so?

Answer (score 3):

I needed it, so I started working on something like that. Check out https://github.com/stuffmc/MCFilteredPeoplePickerNavigationController

Comment: You put a "How to use" but you show nothing about actually filtering.

Comment: It's for the user to filter. But if you look at the code (specifically at `loadContacts` you should find it — check https://github.com/stuffmc/MCFilteredPeoplePickerNavigationController/blob/master/Source/MCFilteredPeoplePickerTableViewController.m#L177

Comment: Ah, I see. I was looking for something where I (as the dev) could filter the list to only show contacts with emails :D

Comment: Turns out that's also something I do, if you look [here](https://github.com/stuffmc/MCFilteredPeoplePickerNavigationController/blob/master/Source/MCFilteredPeoplePickerTableViewController.m#L169) you'll see I only take those contacts having a `kABPersonAddressProperty` (an address).

Answer (score 2):

here is the good blog tutorial for extracting address book values,

http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2009/01/21/cocoa-touch-tutorial-extract-address-book-address-values-on-iphone-os/

try with below:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    [peoplePicker setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];
    [peoplePicker setDisplayedProperties:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty]]];
```

Comment: This code doesn´t answer the question. This displays all the contacts, and when you select it only shows email (or "No email addresses" when the contact is without email).

Answer (score 0):

ABContactHelper is a greater wrapper for the Addressbook and has some methods for filtering contacts based on various things.

https://github.com/erica/ABContactHelper

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do a similar thing.  I've gotten an instance of ABAddressBook, removed the entries I don't want, then set `picker.addressBook = filteredBook`.  It...KINDA works.  The list seems to be filtered, but entries are duplicated like it expects the full list to be there and it just copies existing entries until it has the expected count, or something.

Comment: Did you find a reason / resolution?

Comment: @Wain I did not, I'm afraid.  I haven't really done much with it since.